# incorrect output min stl priority queue for printing top 'm' elements

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

min stl priority queue for storing top 'm' elements out of the entire array is showing an incorrect output. Here in this example, the sorted vector will be [1,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8]. Thus the top 'm' where m = 5 should be 1,3,3,3,3 but the output is 1,3,3,3,5. Could anyone suggest why it is not working in case of duplicate entries. Here is the sample code.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <queue>  
using namespace std;  

 struct compare  
 {  
   bool operator()(const int& l, const int& r)  
   {  
       return l > r;  
   }  
 };  

 int main()  
 {  
     priority_queue<int,vector<int>, compare > pq;  
    vector <int> p;
     p.push_back(3);  
     p.push_back(3);  
     p.push_back(3);  
     p.push_back(3);  
     p.push_back(5);  
     p.push_back(5);  
     p.push_back(5);  
     p.push_back(5);  
     p.push_back(1);  
     p.push_back(8);  
     p.push_back(8);  
     p.push_back(8);  
     p.push_back(8);  
     p.push_back(8); 
    for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++)
{
        int k= p[i];
        if(pq.size() < 5) // top 'm' elements say m = 5 here 
                {
                        pq.push(k);
                }
                else if (pq.top() >= k)
                {
                        pq.pop();
                        pq.push(k);
                }
 }

     while ( !pq.empty() )  
     {  
         cout << pq.top() << endl;  
         pq.pop();  
     }  
     cin.get();  
 }
```

The incorrect output is :

```
1
3
3
3
5
```

but the correct output should be

```
1
3
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The priority queue defined by you is actually pushing values from *lowest* to *highest* from `top` to bottom till the point in code when priority queue `size <= 5`, **but** after that it is *replacing* the currently-lowest value in PQ (equals top of PQ) with the *new* lowest value to be pushed. Consequently, you are *losing the second lowest* value in resulting PQ.

Instead of replacing the lowest value with second lowest, you should be pushing out the highest one (the bottom-most in PQ), which is not possible IMO without using double queue (or stack) implementation, and also not recommended for higher time complexity.

**Solution:**

Change the definition of `pq` from

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>, compare > pq;
```

to

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>> pq;
```

*Get the reverse of PQ to get the answer* :

Do `list::push_front(pq.top)` and pop elements in PQ till PQ becomes empty,
and then print the list using

```
 for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it <<endl;
```

Find [working code here](http://ideone.com/LTw18R)

Comment: the min heap should be built only for top 'm' elements. So how can we constrain the limit on pq instead of storing all the elements? but for that unnecessarily we are pushing all the elements of the array right ? In this case we want only top 'm' minimum elements of a given array just by checking a condition. We just want min heap with 'm' elements. or else its like we are storing all the array elements right ? this code is working for non duplicate entries but not working for duplicate entries

Comment: @ganapathi Constraint on size of `pq` can be applied while doing `push` operation. If pushing increases the size of `pq`, then do `pop` + `push`, else do only `push`.

Comment: @Sauravthanks a lot ! its like we are traversing the pq from bottom and replacing the highest element right

Comment: @ganapathi.. Yes..by doing that you are able to get *rid* of the highest-element-among-lowest-5-till-now at each step and, thus, eventually leaving you will lowest 5(pq size) values in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

When `if(pq.size() < 5)` in your iteration over `p` you fill the `pq` with

```
 3 3 3 3 5
```

after that `else if (pq.top() >= k)` condition do the job and you replace the `top` value `3` with the smallest value in the `p`. It's `1`. So finally you've got:

```
 1 3 3 3 5
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. could you suggest me the best way to retain the top 5 elements in the pq? like 1, 3, 3, 3, 3 are the top 5 elements here right

Comment: @ganapathi You should put all the elements from `p` into the `pq` to get the proper ordering and after that get the top `5` elements.

Comment: but for that unnecessarily we are pushing all the elements of the array right ? In this case we want only top 'm' minimum elements of a given array just by checking a condition. We just want min heap with 'm' elements. or else its like we are storing all the array elements right ?

Comment: @ganapathi Right. To get the minimum elements you should know the order of all elements in `p`. Consider the example `p == 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`. Put to `pq` the first `5` elements `9 8 7 6 5`, `pq == 5 6 7 8 9`. On the next  iteration 5 will be replaced with 4. It's not what you are looking for. Top `5` elements will be the smallest from `p` only if you add all the elements from `p` to `pq` and get the top `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find and store top 5 elements of the vector, consider using `std::partial_sort_copy` instead of `priority_queue`:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr;
std::partial_sort_copy(p.begin(), p.end(), arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

This way you'll get your first 5 elements stored in `arr`.

Sidenote: you can use initializer list to set up your vector in one line

```
vector <int> p{3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,1,8,8,8,8,8};
```

[Working code example](http://ideone.com/J79Rj1)

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following

```
int main()  
{  
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<>> pq;

    for(int i : {3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}) {
        if (pq.size() < 5 || i < pq.top()) {
            pq.push(i);
        }
        if (pq.size() > 5)
        {
            pq.pop();
        }
    }
    while (!pq.empty()) {  
        std::cout << pq.top() << std::endl;  
        pq.pop();  
    }  
}
```

With a reverse display.